# Selecting a list of strings associated with a long list of strings

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists of strings:

```
list1 = {{"ag02",1}, {"mi06",10}, {"ma08",2}, {"ma19",8}, {"ma15",3}};
list2 = {"ag02: Agriculture, hunting, forestry", 
   "ag03: Fishing, aquaculture", 
   "mi06: Mining-quarrying, energy producing products", 
   "mi08: Mining-quarrying, non-energy producing products", 
   "mi09: Mining support service activities", 
   "ma12: Food products,beverages and tobacco", 
   "ma15: Textiles,textile products,leather and footwear", 
   "ma16: Wood and products of wood and cork"};
```

I want to substitute those elements from `list2` including the elements from `list1`. For example, `{"ag02",1}` in `list1` includes `"ag02"` in common in `list2` only as part of the first long name. If that is the case, I want to place that full name from `list2` into `list1` in place of `"ag02"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list1 /. Thread[StringSplit[list2, ": "][[All, 1]] -> list2]
```

returns

```
{{"ag02: Agriculture, hunting, forestry", 1},
 {"mi06: Mining-quarrying, energy producing products", 10},
 {"ma08", 2},
 {"ma19", 8},
 {"ma15: Textiles,textile products,leather and footwear", 3}}
```

Answer (score 5):

To achieve the replacement, we first need to extract the short names from list2 using "StringSplit" und use them to create rules:

```
rules = Rule @@@ ( StringSplit[#, ": "] & /@ list2);
```

These can then be applied to list1:

```
list1 /. rules

{{"Agriculture, hunting, forestry", 1}, {"Mining-quarrying, energy producing products", 10}, {"ma08", 2}, {"ma19", 8}, {"Textiles,textileproducts,leather and footwear", 3}}
```

**Addendum**

If you want the first part of the names included, use:

```
rules = Rule @@@ Transpose[{StringSplit[list2, ":"][[All, 1]], list2}];
list1 /. rules

{{"ag02: Agriculture, hunting, forestry", 1}, {"mi06: Mining-quarrying, energy producing products", 10}, {"ma08", 2}, {"ma19", 8}, {"ma15: Textiles,textile products,leather and footwear", 3}}
```

Comment: `StringSplit` will natively take a list of strings to split, so no need to map over `list2`. You can just write `StringSplit[list2, ": "]`. The required operation then reduces to `list1 /. Rule @@@ StringSplit[list2, ": "]`. (+1)

Comment: @MarcoB  You are right. Thank's for the hint.

Comment: @Daniel Huber: Thanks for the code. The replacement into `list1` should take the full name from `list2`, including strings before `:`. Currently, it only takes the strings after `:`

Comment: @MarcoB: Thank you for your comment, which is an answer also.

Comment: Look at the Addendum in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

An alternate way to build the replacement rules:

```
rulesAlt = Flatten[StringCases[list2, RegularExpression["([^:]*):.*"] -> "$1" -> "$0"]];
list1 /. rules

(* {{"ag02: Agriculture, hunting, forestry", 1}, 
    {"mi06: Mining-quarrying, energy producing products", 10}, 
    {"ma08", 2}, 
    {"ma19", 8}, 
    {"ma15: Textiles,textile products,leather and footwear", 3}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Using `Lookup`:**

This a typical use case for `Lookup`. In this case, admittedly, it provides limited additional benefit.

```
list1 = {{"ag02", 1}, {"mi06", 10}, {"ma08", 2}, {"ma19", 8}, {"ma15",
     3}};
list2 = {"ag02: Agriculture, hunting, forestry", 
   "ag03: Fishing, aquaculture", 
   "mi06: Mining-quarrying, energy producing products", 
   "mi08: Mining-quarrying, non-energy producing products", 
   "mi09: Mining support service activities", 
   "ma12: Food products,beverages and tobacco", 
   "ma15: Textiles,textile products,leather and footwear", 
   "ma16: Wood and products of wood and cork"};
```

---

```
lut = Rule @@@ (StringTrim /@ StringSplit[list2, ":"]);
{Lookup[lut, First@#, First@#], Last@#} & /@ list1
```

> {{"Agriculture, hunting, forestry",    1}, {"Mining-quarrying, energy
> producing products", 10}, {"ma08",    2}, {"ma19", 8},
> {"Textiles,textile products,leather and footwear",    3}}

The third argument for `Lookup` provides a default value. Readers can change it to `Nothing` to see its effect.

---

The output from `Lookup` can be wrapped in a `Head` such as `h` defined as follows:

```
h = Column@StringSplit[#, ","] &

{Lookup[lut, First@#, First@#, h], Last@#} & /@ list1 // 
 Grid[#, Dividers -> All, Alignment -> Left] &
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Very nice, @Syed!

Answer (score 2):

```
list1/.AssociationThread[StringTake[list2,4],list2]

(* {
    {ag02: Agriculture, hunting, forestry,1},
    {mi06: Mining-quarrying, energy producing products,10},
    {ma08,2},
    {ma19,8},
    {ma15: Textiles,textile products,leather and footwear,3}
   } *)
```